# Magnitude of Riemann zeta function on horizontal strip.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Background information: I am doing a problem from my analytic number theory homework, which is asking me to prove the following:

Suppose $s=\sigma +it$,$0<\sigma\leq 1$, $|t|\geq 2$. Suppose $z=x+iy$,$|y|\leq\frac{|t|}{2}$. For any $\epsilon>0$, prove that there exist $A_\epsilon$ such that $$|\zeta(s+z)|\leq A_\epsilon|t|^{\frac{1}{2}-\sigma-x+\epsilon} \tag{1}$$

For all $x<-\sigma$.

I am familiar with the result that given $C$ and $\delta$ positive, then there exist $A_{C,\delta}$ such that$$|\zeta(z)|\leq A_{C,\delta}|t|^{\frac{1}{2}-\sigma-x}\tag{2}$$
For any $z$ such that $-C\leq x \leq \delta$.

Any hint on how to prove this is appreciated. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: No there is a problem with your statement which is anyway hard to parse (problem of quantifiers). Maybe you/they meant just in the critical strip, who knows. The over-exponential growth of $\Gamma$ in the functional equation gives that "for all $x < -\sigma$" is wrong.

Comment: @reuns Sorry for the confusion. This has basically nothing to do with the critical strip, I will look into the "over-exponential growth of $\Gamma$" you mentioned. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: usually in a relation like $1$ it is implied that $|t| \ge |t_0| >0$ or one takes something like $|t|+1$ to avoid non sense for $t=0$; other than that one knows by the functional equation that $|\zeta(s)|=O((|t|+1)^{1/2-\sigma}), s=\sigma+it, \sigma \le -\delta<0$ (and actually this is an asymptotic for large $|t|$)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for the comment. I think there is indeed the requirement $|t|\geq 2$ in the problem. Could you give some more material on the result you mentioned? In my book (The Distribution of Prime Numbers by Dimitris Koukoulopoulos) such result always comes with a lower bound on $\sigma$ (or requires that $|arg(s)|\leq \pi-a$ for some small positive number a).

Comment: Just look at Titchmarsh's bible on RZ (early chapters about the magnitude of RZ in the critical strip where the asymptotic estimate of $\Gamma$, the functional equation and the boundness in $\Re s \ge 1+\delta$ immediately give the result; in general I would consult Titchmarsh about any classical result on RZ since the odds are it's in there; technically for the asymptotic estimate of gamma you need to stay in an angle that has the negative axis outside so for uniform bounds you need $Re s > -C$ too